# GitHub Desktop suddenly not fetching origin, can't push changes

Tags: git, git-commit, git-fetch, github-desktop, git-untracked

We've run into a problem with one of our contributors using GitHub desktop. When they try to push their most recent changes the following error appears

```
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    deleted:    Assets/Audio/Temporary Audio Files (Delete these and this folder when replaced).meta
    deleted:    Assets/Audio/Temporary Audio Files (Delete these and this folder when replaced)/DoorCloseHardWood_S011FO._1.wav
    deleted:    Assets/Audio/Temporary Audio Files (Delete these and this folder when replaced)/DoorCloseHardWood_S011FO._1.wav.meta
    deleted:    Assets/Audio/Temporary Audio Files (Delete these and this folder when replaced)/DoorOpenLatch_S08FO.878.wav
    deleted:    Assets/Audio/Temporary Audio Files (Delete these and this folder when replaced)/DoorOpenLatch_S08FO.878.wav.meta
    deleted:    Assets/Audio/Temporary Audio Files (Delete these and this folder when replaced)/Footstep_temp.mp3
    deleted:    Assets/Audio/Temporary Audio Files (Delete these and this folder when replaced)/Footstep_temp.mp3.meta
    deleted:    Assets/Audio/Temporary Audio Files (Delete these and this folder when replaced)/Mosnter voice in apartment .wav
    deleted:    Assets/Audio/Temporary Audio Files (Delete these and this folder when replaced)/Mosnter voice in apartment .wav.meta
    deleted:    Assets/Audio/Temporary Audio Files (Delete these and this folder when replaced)/Possible Track.mp3
    deleted:    Assets/Audio/Temporary Audio Files (Delete these and this folder when replaced)/Possible Track.mp3.meta
    deleted:    Assets/Audio/Temporary Audio Files (Delete these and this folder when replaced)/Talking behind door .wav
    deleted:    Assets/Audio/Temporary Audio Files (Delete these and this folder when replaced)/Talking behind door .wav.meta
    deleted:    Assets/Audio/Temporary Audio Files (Delete these and this folder when replaced)/Wood Door Knock.mp3
    deleted:    Assets/Audio/Temporary Audio Files (Delete these and this folder when replaced)/Wood Door Knock.mp3.meta
    deleted:    Assets/Audio/Temporary Audio Files (Delete these and this folder when replaced)/ambience 1 Nick .wav
    deleted:    Assets/Audio/Temporary Audio Files (Delete these and this folder when replaced)/ambience 1 Nick .wav.meta
    modified:   Assets/Scenes/mirror level first draft.unity

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    Assets/Audio/Placeholder Audio.meta
    Assets/Audio/Placeholder Audio/

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

We have tried using the add command, as well as add -A, and git commit -a with no success.

After "successfully" adding the files with any of the above commands, when we attempt to push via the command line we are told the files are already up to date.

Something else to note is that within GitHub desktop, the user now sees "Origin never fetched" under the fetch button, even though they had done a fetch and pull right before this issue began occurring.

Besides the command line commands we tried, we have also reinstalled GitHub desktop, logged off / back onto to GitHub desktop, and have removed and re-added the user as a contributor.

Before today this user was having no issues pushing/committing via GitHub desktop.

Comment: Is there any `GIT_xxx` environment variable currently set?

Comment: Those file names seem awfully suspicious: they look like they were auto-generated by some software that needs you to go in and manually fix things up.

Comment: @VonC not to my knowledge no. Other than a git ignore which we setup at the start of the project

Comment: @torek All the files where made by our editors (we really need to standardize our naming conventions). They were added by dragging them into their respective folders within the unity editor

Comment: Does origin refer to an HTTPS URL? And is your `git config credential.helper` set to `manager-core`?

Comment: @VonC the origin is an HTTPS URL yes, it's a repo I made on the GitHub website

The credential.helper is also set to manager core yes

Answer (score 0):

Possible reason and solution to this problem, at least that was it for me: I had moved the location of my repository prior to this, thus I had multiple entries in the "current repository" tab. If the wrong entry is selected, it might still work, but it can also lead to problems..  I can't really recall everything else that happened, so I'll just say.. Github Desktop gets confused and things get weird.

Switching to the "correct" entry fixed the problem, then I deleted the old entries so it wouldn't confuse me again.